# CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER seems to have no effect

Tags: django, celery

I have a Django + Celery setup working correctly in production with RabbitMQ.

AFAIK, it should be sufficient to set `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` to `True` in django settings locally, to avoid setting up RabbitMQ for development. I have done this but when calling .delay() on a task I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 89, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 215, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "app/web/views.py", line 188, in form_valid
    form.send_email()
  File "app/web/forms.py", line 17, in send_email
    send_email.delay(mail, recipients, 'Contact %s' % name, comment)
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 453, in delay
    return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 559, in apply_async
    **dict(self._get_exec_options(), **options)
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 353, in send_task
    reply_to=reply_to or self.oid, **options
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 305, in publish_task
    **kwargs
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 172, in publish
    routing_key, mandatory, immediate, exchange, declare)
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 457, in _ensured
    interval_max)
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 369, in ensure_connection
    interval_start, interval_step, interval_max, callback)
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 243, in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 237, in connect
    return self.connection
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 741, in connection
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 696, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/librabbitmq.py", line 123, in establish_connection
    conn = self.Connection(**opts)
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/librabbitmq/__init__.py", line 199, in __init__
    self.connect()
ConnectionError: Error opening socket: a socket error occurred
```

Comment: Can you post your settings, this could be due to the fact that option is not taken in account on startup for some kind of mistake.

Comment: Thanks Mauro, that was not the issue. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have found the problem. Basically I was missing:

`from .celery import app as celery_app`

in `proj/proj/__init__.py`

For some misterious reason this seems to fail only when running `runserver` and not when running `wsgi.py` via `uWSGI`. Not sure why, but with the import it works on `runserver` too.

Comment: could you elaborate more on this fix? for me still seems not working. by importing from .celery you mean some of your apps or celery package?

Comment: Hey andi. I mean the celery package. Assuming you run `django-admin startproject proj` you should have this in your `proj/__init__.py`: 

```from .celery import app as celery_app

__app = celery_app```

Answer (score 10):

For the record, since [celery 4.0](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/whatsnew-4.0.html?highlight=celery_always_eager) this setting has been renamed to [task_always_eager](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/4.0/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-task_always_eager):

```
# setting renamed on celery 4.0
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER --> task_always_eager
```

To help the migration to this version, Celery provides the following util to update automatically your settings:

```
# --django allows to keep uppercase settings and CELERY_ prefix
$ celery upgrade settings proj/settings.py --django
```

Comment: Of course, who would dream that renaming the variable that allows you to test asynchronous tasks that give no output or logs would cause any confusion. Just let things fail silently, no worries.